# Edit all selected items into one editor

Tags: qt, qtableview

Using QTableView I would like to be able to select multiple cells and change all selected cells at once. How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "changing" the selected cells (content, formatting, something else?) but I think `QTableView::selectedIndexes()` (or `QTableView::selectionModel()` if you need more power) is going to help out. You can loop through the returned indexes and update your underlying model.

If you are using a `QSortFilterProxyModel` you will have to use the `QSortFilterProxyModel::mapFromSource()` and related methods to map from the selected cells on your table view to the actual model indexes.

Comment: Solved by sending selected QModelIndex to my model and overload setData with it. Thank you.